# Linux kickstart select default image

Tags: linux, kickstart, pxe

I have following kickstart `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg` file with following content, I am looking for option where my kickstart default boot from  `centos6-64` image is no human interaction happened, how do i do that?

```
DEFAULT menu
PROMPT 0
MENU TITLE Cobbler | http://www.cobblerd.org/
TIMEOUT 200
TOTALTIMEOUT 6000
ONTIMEOUT local

LABEL local
        MENU LABEL (local)
        MENU DEFAULT
        LOCALBOOT -1

LABEL centos5-32
        kernel /images/centos5/vmlinuz
        MENU LABEL centos5-32
        append initrd=/images/centos5/initrd.img ksdevice=eth0 lang=  console=ttyS1,115200 text dd=http://10.5.0.50/hp/centos/5.11/i686/dd.img noapic nolapic kssendmac vmalloc=384M  ks=http://10.10.10.1/cblr/svc/op/ks/profile/centos5-32
        ipappend 2

LABEL centos6-64
        kernel /images/centos6/vmlinuz
        MENU LABEL centos6-64
        append initrd=/images/centos6/initrd.img ksdevice=eth0 lang=  noapic text nolapic kssendmac console=ttyS1,118200  ks=http://10.10.10.1/cblr/svc/op/ks/profile/centos6-64
        ipappend 2
```

Comment: what happens if you change `DEFAULT menu` to `DEFAULT centos6-64` ?

Comment: If I does that then I'm not seething menu and it directly start kick-starting using that image.

Comment: then what are you trying to do?